# Is it possible to switch Backbone.$ to minified.js?

Tags: backbone.js

jQuery to big for me even minified and zipped. So I want to ask is it possible to switch Backbone.$ to http://minifiedjs.com/ I have tryed with manual https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/wiki/Using-Backbone-without-jQuery but Backbone.$ becomes empty

Comment: Are you placing the minifiedjs `<script>` tag before the Backbone script tag? And are you using AMD for module loading? Need a little more info here.

Comment: I have used browserify to build it. In the top of file add `var minified = require('minfied'); var Backbone = require('backbone');` In the package.json added `{
    "browserify" {
        "transform": ["aliasify"]
    },
    "aliasify": {
        "aliases": {
            "jquery": "minified"
        }
    }
}` Build with grunt using grunt-contrib-browserify

Comment: Hmm, so then does `require("jquery");` return the minified instance? I'd recommend setting up a break point in Backbone's source around [here](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-4) where `Backbone.$` is being set.  Backbone will either look for `window.$` (via `self), or `global`) on the server, OR it will try to pull it in with `require("jquery");`.  Try to figure out which it's doing and go from there.